# DataMapper: one-to-many relationship with custom name?

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I'm trying to build a small model consisting of two entities. For the purposes of this question, call them `A` and `B`. `A` has a one-to-many relationship to several `B`s; this means that each `B` `belongs_to` an `A`.

In this particular case, I'd like to call the relationship from `B` back to `A` something other than `a`. I think I got close with the following:

```
class A
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    has n, :bs
end

class B
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    belongs_to :owner, 'A'
end
```

The important bit here is the `belongs_to :owner, 'A'` line in `B`. With this, I can successfully:

- Create and save an instance of `A`
- Query that `A` for its `bs` and get an empty array back
- Create an instance of `B`, assigning its `owner` to be the `A` I made earlier

However, when I go to save that instance of `B`, I run into trouble – calling `save` returns `false`. If I print the `B`, I see that it has **two** attributes: one called `owner_id` and another called `a_id`.

What else do I need to do with this model to rename the relationship from `B` back to `A`? Is such a rename even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The owning entity (`A`) needs to explicitly specify the child keys that it wants created for the relationship:

```
class A
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    has n, :bs, :child_key => [ 'owner_id' ]
end

class B
    include DataMapper::Resource
    property :id, Serial
    belongs_to :owner, 'A'
end
```

With this change, I only see one relationship attribute created on `B`, and I'm able to save instances of `B` that I create.